# How to add units to uses clause of current unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I just started exploring the capabilities of live templates (using Delphi XE4), and ran into a question.  Some templates that I have made create code that requires certain units to be added to my uses clause in order to function.

How can I make my template automatically add the required units to the uses clause if they aren't already included?  My initial guess is that I need to make a custom scripting engine in order to do this, and I have found a few articles that seem to contain sufficient information for me to create a scripting engine without much hassle.  However, I don't know how to make the scripting engine actually perform my desired task.  I assume that I need to use the Open Tools Api, but I don't know how to do that.

If I am on the right track, could somebody please share some information that would help me proceed down it?  Otherwise, could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: The CnPack IDE Wizard has that scripting functionality, could use that to avoid the hassle.

Comment: You've came to the right conclusion, OTA does not provide such functionality (as in .NET's CodeDOM, for example). You have to interpret existing `uses` clause(s) and then add a desired unit. Additionally you will have to expose your new function to the Live Template scripting engine.

Answer (score 0):

Open Tools Api does not provide such functionality (as in .NET's CodeDOM, for example). You have to interpret existing uses clause(s) and then add a desired unit. Additionally you will have to expose your new function to the Live Template scripting engine.